# Scala: For loop on dataframe, create new column from existing by index

Tags: scala, apache-spark, for-loop, calculated-columns, databricks

I have a dataframe with two columns:

> id (string), date (timestamp)

I would like to loop through the dataframe, and add a new column with an url, which includes the id. The algorithm should look something like this:

```
 add one new column with the following value:
 for each id
       "some url" + the value of the dataframe's id column
```

I tried to make this work in Scala, but I have problems with getting the specific id on the index of "a"

```
 val k = df2.count().asInstanceOf[Int]
      // for loop execution with a range
      for( a <- 1 to k){
         // println( "Value of a: " + a );
         val dfWithFileURL = dataframe.withColumn("fileUrl", "https://someURL/" + dataframe("id")[a])

      }
```

But this

> dataframe("id")[a]

is not working with Scala. I could not find solution yet, so every kind of suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Do you even need a loop? `df2.withColumn("fileUrl", "https://someURL/" + $"id")` might work?

Comment: You want to add as many columns as there is rows ? This won't scale at all and if you don't need it to be scalable, there is not reason to use a Spark DataFrame...

Comment: So the solution of @zacdav throws the following error: 
error: type mismatch;
 found   : String
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column

I'm working in a Databricks notebook, maybe it works in a different way? I try to investigate this too...

Comment: By the way, @eliasah, no, I want to add one column only with a url, which has the id added to the link, the id comes from the first column.

Comment: Then your pseudo-code is wrong because this is what it does.

Comment: You are right, it is misleading... I fix it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the `withColumn` function in Scala, something like this:

```
val df = Seq(
  ( 1, "1 Jan 2000" ),
  ( 2, "2 Feb 2014" ),
  ( 3, "3 Apr 2017" )
)
  .toDF("id", "date" )


// Add the fileUrl column
val dfNew = df
  .withColumn("fileUrl", concat(lit("https://someURL/"), $"id"))
  .show
```

My results:

[image: scala results]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you require but you can use `zipWithIndex` for indexing.

```
data.show()

+---+---------------+
| Id|            Url|
+---+---------------+
|111|http://abc.go.org/|
|222|http://xyz.go.net/|
+---+---------------+   

import org.apache.spark.sql._
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
data.rdd.zipWithIndex
.map{case (r, i) => Row.fromSeq(r.toSeq:+(s"""${r.getString(1)}${i+1}"""))},
    StructType(data.schema.fields :+ StructField("fileUrl", StringType, false))
)
```

Output:

```
df.show(false)

+---+---------------+----------------+
|Id |Url            |fileUrl         |
+---+---------------+----------------+
|111|http://abc.go.org/|http://abc.go.org/1|
|222|http://xyz.go.net/|http://xyz.go.net/2|
+---+---------------+----------------+
```